# Non-Live Linux on USB on Gigabyte Z77 D3H Strange Freezes

Tags: usb, freeze

I have installed ubuntu on a 32 GB sandisk. It works everywhere perfectly except my i5-3570k on Gigabyte z77-d3h. I know this board has USB 3.0 so I have disabled XCHI on bios. I am still having strange freezes. Windows gray out. Programs launch very slow. Keyboard input freezes and then writes from keyboard buffer. I have no idea whats going on. I have bench-marked the usb could not identify something strange (I could not maybe you can).

Could you guide me please to understand and fix whats going on. I am really up to resoldering antoher usb controller if it is possible. Or adding a USB pci card. But I am not really sure if its the driver or the hardware or something else .

Please guide me.

Comment: An installed Ubuntu is "portable" when the hardware is the same or very similar and neither machine requires proprietary drivers. Graphics is what typically spoils the party. Many Nvidia cards need proprietary drivers to work as expected. Without it, the OS may perform badly (like you describe) or even have no video. But then you can't install the required drivers because it will mess up the boot in other machines.

Comment: Its not something like that. It works and performs perfectly only strange freezes time to time. Therefore I suspect from USB drivers or VM Swappiness. I installed powertop and iotop I will also install pstree and will keep looking for it. But I dont thinks the problem is what you describe. I need a concrete evidence to confirm if it is GPU driver oriented. ı dont see that on games or glxtree or using compiz. It also freezes with metacity.